# Set Deep Link in Pushwoosh

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, push-notification, deep-learning, pushwoosh

How set Deep Link in Pushwoosh,I want open page etc. **page.html?id=1** 
I use VS 2015 and apache cordova for android.

Here is [documentation](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/deep-linking) but I don't understend how set that!

I'm set com.pushwoosh://page.html?id=1  but not open!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin
It's super easy to set deep links for Cordova there and it works with Pushwoosh deep linking functionality.

To cordova config add:

```
<universal-links>
<host name="sample.com" scheme="pushwoosh" event="ul_myExampleEvent" />
</universal-links>
```

To your code add:

```
universalLinks.subscribe('ul_myExampleEvent', function (eventData) {
// do some work
// in eventData you'll see url и and parsed url with schema, host, path and arguments
console.log('Did launch application from the link: ' + JSON.stringify(eventData));
alert('Did launch application from the link: ' + JSON.stringify(eventData));
```

});

Then use simple redirection with Cordova.
That's it!

P.S. I'll add this to the guide. Thanks!